# Custom buttons with multiple UILabel and images

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I was wondering if anyone had any insight as to the best way to create a UIButton with two or more labels (or basically two lines with different styling) and one or more images. The closest example of what I am trying to do is the Evernote iPhone compose screen where each button has an icon and one or more UILabels (the Twitter app for iPhone employes a similar button style).  Here's a screenshot:
[image]

My question is basically whether it is best to sub-class UIButton or to add the individual labels and images as subviews of the UIButton.

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with subclassing for two reasons:

1. You're not supposed to mess with the subviews of standard UI controls.
2. A subclass would be easier to manage if you need to update the labels, etc.

The next question is what class should you subclass? I haven't tried subclassing UIButton, but I don't see why it'd be a problem. On the other hand, what do you get from UIButton that you wouldn't also get from UIControl? Subclassing UIControl might give you a cleaner implementation.

Comment: Thanks Caleb. Yes I had thought sub-classing would be a better option but hadn't considered using UIControl instead of UIButton. Will explore that option.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could think of to do this would be to subclass a UIButton and add your own UILabels and UIImageViews to it in that way.